# Is an empty array always interpreted as TRUE?

Tags: javascript, arrays, truthiness

Is this the case in **all browser** versions? Meaning, an empty array is always considered as TRUE and never as FALSE as a boolean representation?

```
var x = [];

if(x)
   alert('this could be an empty array');
else
    alert('this could NEVER be an empty array');
```

Comment: Yes it is. That's why you'd use something like isempty/isset or count to see if it's empty or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [ECMA Script 5.1 specification's Boolean expression evaluation function](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2), any object will be always evaluated to be Truthy. So, an array will be always evaluated to be truthy.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Argument Type | Result                                                |
|:--------------|------------------------------------------------------:|
| Undefined     | false                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Null          | false                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Boolean       | The result equals the input argument (no conversion). |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Number        | The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN;|
|               | otherwise the result is true.                         |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| String        | The result is false if the argument is the empty      |
|               | String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is  |
|               | true.                                                 |
|---------------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Object        | true                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

As per the last line, for any Object, result will be `true`.

Reference: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905264/1903116) to the other question in SO

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are truthy, yes. If you want an easy way to check for emptiness, use the `length` property:

```
var x = [];

if(x.length)
    alert('this array is not empty');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. All objects are truthy. Always.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Array is an object. So it is true. whereas, null/undefined is false

Answer (score 0):

by default these are things are treated as false in javascript.

1. false
2. null
3. undefined
4. '' or "" [empty string]
5. 0 [zero]

Comment: "By default"? If you're going to say things like that, you should also at least give a cursory mention of when that behavior does not apply. (Though I can't think of any circumstances where the above is not true.)

Comment: simple, you using other than these then result will be true.