# Checking for null in JavaScript works except for zero

Tags: javascript, null

I'm using the following syntax to ensure that my input parameters aren't *null*.

```
function hazaa(shazoo){
  shazoo = shazoo || " ";
}
```

It works for everything I tested for **except** the zero.

> null -> " "
>   "beep" -> "beep"
>   4 -> 4
>   but...
>   0 -> " "

I'm guessing that the zero is regarded as *null* or *false*, hence creating the gotcha. What's the syntax to get it right, so that zero is zero?

If it makes the issue considerably simpler to suggest a syntax, we can assume that the input is going to be a char, string, number or null.

Comment: Check for just null, `shazoo = shazoo === null ? " " : shazoo;`

Comment: @adeneo So... Many... Bytes...   :)    (But yes, it's working now, hahaha.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is one of the few places where you don't want to do a typesafe comparison.
In such places you want to threat undefined the same way as null; and you don't want to write it every time.

```
//so better use this
shazoo = shazoo == null ? " " : shazoo;

//than this
shazoo = shazoo === null || shazoo === undefined ? " " : shazoo;
```

Answer (score 7):

> I'm using the following syntax to ensure that my input parameters aren't null.

If all you are trying to do is to use `" "` only if the input is `null`, then use ternary operator, like this

```
shazoo = shazoo === null ? " " : shazoo;
```

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905264/1903116) lists the values which are considered as Falsy in JavaScript. The table shows that zeroes are considered as Falsy. That is why `shazoo || " "` is evaluated to be `" "`, when `shazoo` is zero.

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean(0)` outputs `false`, so it took second option `""`

you can try (check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3bvgp0ct/))

```
function hazaa(shazoo){
  return shazoo == null ? " " : shazoo;
} 
hazaa(0); //output 0
```

Comment: *"`0 == false` outputs `true`"* while this is correct, that is not what happens here. **Comparing** a value to a Boolean is very different from **converting** a value to a Boolean (which is what `||` does). `0 == false` actually ends up being `0 == 0`. The correct explanation is hat `Boolean(0)` is `false`. This might be more convincing  if you apply your explanation to `null`: `null == false` is `false` and yet `null || ""` returns `""`. `Boolean(null)` is `false` however.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm guessing that the zero is regarded as null or false

Yes 0 is treated as false.

> What's the syntax to get it right, so that zero is zero?

You can try to use

```
shazoo = shazoo === null ? " " : shazoo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
if (shazoo === null){
...
}else{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can us `===` operator and the best way would be

```
if (shazoo === null)
 shazoo = " ";
```

No need to use else

`shazoo = shazoo //no sense`

Answer (score 1):

**New notation**

You can also in ES6 use the default argument notation that will default if `undefined` is passed for that argument.

```
function foo(shazoo = "default"){
    console.log(shazoo);
}

foo();          // "default"
foo(undefined); // "default"
var bar;        // 
foo(bar);       // "default"
foo("my string"); // "my string"
foo(null);      // null
```

It does not handle `null`

Comment: @KonradViltersten ES6 is  ECMAScript6 is the latest version of JavaScript. Though there is still not full support on current browsers. Here is a rundown for ES6 support in Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla